# How to check if value is in dictionary or why it isn't working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter, pandastable

Currently I'm trying to make a leaderboard and I want to check if the name of the person is already on the board so it doesn't keep adding to the dictionary

[image]

I've tried checking if it's there by using this line:

```
if ("Name", str(self.names[self.i-1])) not in self.places.items():
```

The dictionary (before any data is in it) looks like this:

```
self.places = {"Place":[], "Name":[], "Time":[]}
```

and here is the full code (lines for where the problem occurs is 330-340:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
from time import sleep as wait
from functools import partial
from tkinter import Toplevel, filedialog as fd
import serial
import threading
import customtkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

lapRemainingPeople = {}

#serial communcation for arduino
serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "COM3", baudrate=115200,
                           bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

serialString = ""

window = tk.CTk()
window.title('Slot Car UI')

buttonIdentities = []
nameIdentities = []
frameIdentities = []
oRnameIdentities = []
ChoosenameIdentities = []
chooseImageIdentities = []
lapTimeIdentities = []
bestTimeIdentities = []
yCoordinates = []

window.geometry("500x500")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

class image():
    def __init__(self, Laps, Players, frameIdentities, lapRemainingPeople):
        self.lapRemainingPeople = lapRemainingPeople
        self.Laps = Laps
        self.Players = Players
        self.nameIdentities = nameIdentities
        self.buttonIdentities = buttonIdentities
        self.frameIdentities = frameIdentities
        self.oRnameIdentities = oRnameIdentities
        self.ChoosenameIdentities = ChoosenameIdentities
        self.chooseImageIdentities = chooseImageIdentities
        self.lapTimeIdentities = lapTimeIdentities
        self.bestTimeIdentities = bestTimeIdentities
        self.yCoordinates = yCoordinates
        self.terminate = True
        self.Truth = False
        self.names = []
        threading.Thread(target=self.serialReading).start()
        self.places = {"Place":[], "Name":[], "Time":[]}

    def select_file_car(self, percent):
        #Choosing car image from file

        self.filetypes = (('Images', '*.png'),('All files', '*.*'))
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename(title='Open a file', initialdir='/', filetypes=self.filetypes)

        self.photo = cv2.imread(self.filename)

        #dynamically resizing the photo to be fitted perfectly in the frame. Also puts the image in the middle
        scale_percent = percent
        self.width = int(self.photo.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        self.height = int(self.photo.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (self.width, self.height)

        if self.width > 250:
            while self.width > 250:
                scale_percent -= 1
                self.width = int(self.photo.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
                self.height = int(self.photo.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
                dim = (self.width, self.height)

        if self.width < 250:
            while self.width < 250:
                scale_percent += 1
                self.width = int(self.photo.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
                self.height = int(self.photo.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
                dim = (self.width, self.height)

        resized = cv2.resize(self.photo, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)

        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)

        self.Ycords = self.height + 210

        yCoordinates.append(self.Ycords)

        self.lapsRemaining.place(x=0, y=self.Ycords)

        middle = ((270 - self.width) / 2) - 2
        label = tk.CTkLabel(self.frame)  
        label.imgtk = self.imgtk
        label.configure(image=self.imgtk)
        label.place(x=middle, y=200)
        self.chooseImage.destroy()

    def select_file_person(self, percent):
        #Choosing a face from a file

        self.filetypes = (('Images', '*.png'),('All files', '*.*'))
        self.filename = fd .askopenfilename(title='Open a file', initialdir='/', filetypes=self.filetypes)

        self.photo = cv2.imread(self.filename)

        #resizing the photo
        scale_percent = percent 
        self.width = int(self.photo.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
        self.height = int(self.photo.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
        dim = (self.width, self.height)
        
        if self.width > 180:
            while self.width > 180:
                scale_percent -= 1
                self.width = int(self.photo.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
                self.height = int(self.photo.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
                dim = (self.width, self.height)
        
        if self.width < 180:
            while self.width < 180:
                scale_percent += 1
                self.width = int(self.photo.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
                self.height = int(self.photo.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
                dim = (self.width, self.height)

        resized = cv2.resize(self.photo, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)   

        self.capture_image(1) 

    def capture_image(self, Truth):
        global label

        label = tk.CTkLabel(self.frame)

        #if Truth equals 0 then take an image from the webcam
        if Truth == 0:
            i = 3
            for i in range(3, 0, -1):
                self.bname.configure(text=str(i))
                window.update()
                wait(1)
            
            scale_percent = 25 
            self.width = int(cap.read()[1].shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
            self.height = int(cap.read()[1].shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
            dim = (self.width, self.height)

            if self.width > 180:
                while self.width > 180:
                    scale_percent -= 1
                    self.width = int(cap.read()[1].shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
                    self.height = int(cap.read()[1].shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
                    dim = (self.width, self.height)
            
            if self.width < 180:
                while self.width < 180:
                    scale_percent += 1
                    self.width = int(cap.read()[1].shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
                    self.height = int(cap.read()[1].shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
                    dim = (self.width, self.height)
        
            
            resized = cv2.resize(cap.read()[1], dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

            cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            
            self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img) 
        
        #If Truth does not equal 0 then pass the option to grab an image and use the image from a file instead
        else:
            pass
        
        label.imgtk = self.imgtk
        label.configure(image=self.imgtk)

        label.imgtk = self.imgtk

        #Makes the name for the person that is running the slot clar as well as getting the what row it is on
        name = self.ename.get()
        self.names.append(name)
        self.labelName = tk.CTkLabel(self.frame, text = str(self.n+1) + ': ' + str(name), text_font=("Arial", 18))

        self.frame.config(width=270, height=500)

        self.lastLap = tk.CTkLabel(self.frame, text = 'Last Lap:', width = 65)
        self.bestLap = tk.CTkLabel(self.frame, text = 'Best Lap:', width = 65)
        self.lapsRemaining = tk.CTkLabel(self.frame, text = 'Laps Remaining', width = 100)

        b = self.n * 300 + 280

        window.geometry(str(self.winWidth) + 'x550')
        
        if b >= self.winWidth:
            window.geometry(str(b) + 'x550')

        #if button pressed == 0 then place the frame at the start 
        if self.n == 0:
            self.frame.place(x=10, y=10)

        #If button pressed is anything but 0 then place using simple formula
        else:
            l = self.n * 300
            self.frame.place(x=l, y=10)
        
        #place buttons and labels
        self.lastLap.place(x=0, y=60)
        self.bestLap.place(x=0, y=120)
        self.labelName.place(x=0, y=10)
        label.place(x=120, y=60)

        window.update()
        self.labelname_width = self.labelName.winfo_width()
        middle = (270 - self.labelname_width) / 2

        label_width = label.winfo_width()
        right = (270 - label_width) - 5

        label.place(x=right, y=60)
        self.labelName.place(x=middle, y=10)

        self.bname.destroy()
        self.ename.destroy()
        self.cname.destroy()
        self.oRname.destroy()

        self.chooseImage.place(x=0, y=200)

    def whatClick(self, n, Truth):
        #Checks what has been pressed
        self.n = n
        self.oRname = (self.oRnameIdentities[self.n])
        self.cname = (self.ChoosenameIdentities[self.n]) 
        self.ename = (self.nameIdentities[self.n])
        self.bname = (self.buttonIdentities[self.n])
        self.frame = (self.frameIdentities[self.n])

        for k in range(self.Players):
            #makes the choose image identities 
            self.chooseImage = tk.CTkButton(self.frame, text='choose image', command = lambda a = 70: self.select_file_car(a))
            self.chooseImageIdentities.append(self.chooseImage)

        self.Choose = (self.ChoosenameIdentities[self.n])

        #checks what truth is
        if Truth == 0:
            self.capture_image(Truth)
        if Truth == 1:
            self.select_file_person(70)

    def Data(self):
        p = 10
        i = 0
        for k in range(self.Players):
            #appends identities for tkinter buttons/widgets
            self.shoot = tk.CTkButton(window, text = 'Shoot', command = partial(self.whatClick, k, 0))
            self.name = tk.CTkEntry(window) 
            self.oR = tk.CTkLabel(window, text='or')
            self.choose = tk.CTkButton(window, text='Image', command = partial(self.whatClick, k, 1))
            
            b = p+60
            z = b+25
            self.shoot.place(x=p, y=10, width=55)
            self.oR.place(x=b, y=10, width=20)
            self.choose.place(x=z, y=10, width=55)
            self.name.place(x=p, y=50)

            p += 300
            i+=1
            self.nameIdentities.append(self.name)
            self.buttonIdentities.append(self.shoot)
            self.ChoosenameIdentities.append(self.choose)
            self.oRnameIdentities.append(self.oR)   
        
        if self.Players == 1:
            self.winWidth = 160
            window.geometry(str(self.winWidth) + 'x250')
        
        else:
            self.winWidth = (self.Players * 300) - 140
            window.geometry(str(self.winWidth) + 'x250')

    def LeaderBoard(self):
        if self.Truth == False:
            self.leaderboard = tk.CTkToplevel(window)
            self.statsFrame = tk.CTkFrame(self.leaderboard)
            self.statsFrame.pack()
            self.Truth = True
        self.stats = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.places)
        self.table = Table(self.statsFrame, dataframe=self.stats)
        self.table.show()

    def serialReading(self):   
        while(self.terminate == True):
                if(serialPort.in_waiting > 0):
                    self.serialString = serialPort.readline()
                    self.string = self.serialString.decode('Ascii')

                    self.numbers = 0
                        
                    try:
                        for self.i in range(len(self.frameIdentities)):
                            self.i+=1
                            if self.i == int(self.string.split(' ')[1]):
                                try:   
                                    self.lapRemainingPeople['serialTime'+str(self.i-1)] -=1

                                    self.BestLap = tk.CTkLabel(self.frameIdentities[self.i-1], text = str(self.string.split(' ')[7]))
                                    self.laps = tk.CTkLabel(self.frameIdentities[self.i-1], text = str(self.string.split(' ')[4]))
                                    self.lapsRem = tk.CTkLabel(self.frameIdentities[self.i-1], text=str(self.lapRemainingPeople['serialTime' + str(self.i-1)]), text_font=("Arial", 36))
                                    
                                    y = self.yCoordinates[self.i-1] + 30
                                    self.lapsRem.place(x=65, y=y)
                                    self.BestLap.place(x=0, y=140, width=65)
                                    self.laps.place(x=0, y=80, width=65)

                                    if self.lapRemainingPeople['serialTime'+str(self.i-1)] <= 0:
                                        print(('Name', 'Noah') in self.places.items())
                                        print(self.places["Name"])
                                        if ("Name", str(self.names[self.i-1])) not in self.places.items():                      
                                            self.lapsRem.configure(text='0')
                                            self.places["Place"].append('not ready')
                                            self.places["Name"].append(self.names[self.i-1])
                                            self.places["Time"].append('1.95')
                                            self.LeaderBoard()
                                        else:
                                            self.lapsRem.configure(text='0')

                                except:
                                    pass

                    except:
                        pass

def entryGet():
    global Image__

    def frames(Players):
        #makes frame identities
        global frameIdentities
        players = Players + 1
        for data in range(players):
            frame = tk.CTkFrame(window, highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=2)
            lapRemainingPeople["serialTime"+str(data)] = int(laps.get())
            frameIdentities.append(frame)

    try:
        #Tries to do class 
        Players = int(entry.get())
        frames(Players)
        Image__ = image(Laps, Players, frameIdentities, lapRemainingPeople)
        Image__.Data()
        entry.destroy()
        entryName.destroy()
        laps.destroy()
        Laps.destroy()
    except ValueError:
        #if entry is not a number then don't for class
        entry.delete('0', tk.END)
        entry.insert('0', 'Not Valid')  

Laps = tk.CTkLabel(window, text='How Many Laps')
Laps.pack()

laps = tk.CTkEntry(window)
laps.pack()

entryName = tk.CTkLabel(window, text='How Many Players')
entryName.pack()

#Makes an entry box to get the amount of players
entry = tk.CTkEntry(window)
entry.pack()

#binds a key to when pressed to entryGet()
window.bind('<Return>', lambda event: entryGet())

window.mainloop()
```

Please keep in mind that I'm not a professional at coding so the structure might look very slopy.

Comment: You can use `print(("Name", str(self.names[self.i-1]))` and make sure it is what you expect it to be. Also, we shouldn't have to look through 50+ lines of code just to see the error which is a very small part. Instead we should be given a small code that will be able to reproduce your error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict["Key"]` to return the value of a specific key.

In this case, `self.places["Name"]` will return a `list[str]` of the names:

```py
if (name not in self.places["Name"]):
    # Add name to dictionary
```

where `name` is the name you want to check.

Alternatively, you can use `dict.get("key")` to return the list of names

```py
if (name not in self.places.get("Name")):
    # Add name to dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
print(name_variable in set(df['Name']))
```